# Where is the "caucho.com" new Maven2 repository address?

Tags: maven-2, jakarta-ee, resin, caucho

I add the "http://caucho.com/m2" or "http://caucho.com/m2-snapshot" repository address but is error .Message is

```
Unable to update index for caucho release repository|http://caucho.com/m2: Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist
```

Where is the new address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Caucho repository does NOT provide a Nexus index and you can't search it with m2eclipse, that's all. But this doesn't mean the repository doesn't work.

Comment: @EdwardLau Declare it as you like (in a profile or not), it doesn't matter. Providing a nexus index is just handy to make the repository searchable. Not providing a Nexus index doesn't make the repository unusable.

Comment: @Edward No problem. Feel free to ask questions :)